# Magento 2 : 404 issue

Tags: magento2, 404-page

1. Magento 2 'Home Page'

throws "Invalid Document Element 'type': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'" in developer mode

but it's coming fine in production mode.

All other pages (such as http://example.com/admin, http://example.com/contact, http://example.com/catalogsearch/advanced/ ) gives 404 error in both developer and production mode.

Note : above such are done with 'var' and 'pub' directories recursively given 777 permission.

2. It also gives "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from....." may be because of the same issue.

Though SOAP is enabled, IP in host file is okay but SOAP connection gets failed.

Note:

I already followed the solutions given in magento forums and stackoverflow, stackexchange.. etc, But the problem still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been solved by following the below steps:

1. i. applying proper permissions, ii. enable apache rewrite_module iii. refresh apache server.

   `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/MAGENTO_2_ROOT_DIRECTORY/
   sudo a2enmod rewrite
   sudo service apache2 restart`
2. run following command from Magento root:

   `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
3. Now clear var directory except .htaccess file and check admin. If still the issue persists, then it may be because of Symlink. 
   For this, Edit apache config file

   `sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

and replace this code :

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride none
Require all granted

with

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```

Note: changed AllowOverride none to AllowOverride All

Now restart apache `sudo service apache2 restart` and check admin. This should fix admin 404 issue.

4. Also make sure, you don't leave `/app/etc/ directory` writable

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem comes from the xml of a theme or a module. The fact that it "works fine" in production mode is just that the errors are not displayed but logged (`var/log/` most probably or `var/report/`).